# How to get the Session Token of a Standard User

Tags: webservices, authentication, session, rest-service

I would like to simulate some web service calls, for which I need the Session Token.  With an Admin user, I can simply click on the Developer Console and get UserInfo.getSessionId().  However, with a standard user, the Developer Console does not show up.

I thought of a workaround - log in as an admin, then log in as a standard user who has granted admins login access.  This gives me the Console, but when I open it it gives me an Internal Server Error.

Is there any way to get the Standard User's Session Token?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the session token from the cookie of the browser. The name of the cookie is 'sid'. In Chrome, you can find the cookie by going to settings->advanced settings->privacy->content settings->allcookie and site data and then seacrch for yourinstance.salesforce.com and select the sid cookie and the copy the content of this cookie.